# filter 1D character vector according to length of substrings

Tags: r, string

I have this character vector:

```
protein = "ARTKQTARKSTGGKAPRKQLATKAARKSAPATGGVKKPHRYRPGTVALREIRRYQKSTELLIRKLPFQRLVREIAQDFKTDLRFQSSAVMALQEACEAYLVGLFEDTNLCAIHAKRVTIMPKDIQLARRIRGERA"
```

I want to fragment it according to the occurrence of the letter R.

```
peptide_fragments <- str_split(protein, "(?<=[R])")
```

Now from the resulting fragments, I want to omit the substrings that:

1. don't contain the letter K

Then from the remaining substrings to omit:

2. those whose character length is less than 6.

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Using a pure base R regex approach we can try:

```r
protein <- "ARTKQTARKSTGGKAPRKQLATKAARKSAPATGGVKKPHRYRPGTVALREIRRYQKSTELLIRKLPFQRLVREIAQDFKTDLRFQSSAVMALQEACEAYLVGLFEDTNLCAIHAKRVTIMPKDIQLARRIRGERA"
parts <- strsplit(protein, "(?<=R)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
output <- grep("^(?=.*K).{6,}$", parts, value=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "TKQTAR"                            "KSTGGKAPR"                        
[3] "KQLATKAAR"                         "KSAPATGGVKKPHR"                   
[5] "YQKSTELLIR"                        "KLPFQR"                           
[7] "EIAQDFKTDLR"                       "FQSSAVMALQEACEAYLVGLFEDTNLCAIHAKR"
[9] "VTIMPKDIQLAR"
```

Comment: This also does the Job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split **after** "R":

```
temp <-  unlist(str_split(protein, "(?<=R)"))
res <- temp[grepl("K", temp) & !nchar(temp) < 6]
```

Result:

```
res
[1] "TKQTAR"                            "KSTGGKAPR"                        
[3] "KQLATKAAR"                         "KSAPATGGVKKPHR"                   
[5] "YQKSTELLIR"                        "KLPFQR"                           
[7] "EIAQDFKTDLR"                       "FQSSAVMALQEACEAYLVGLFEDTNLCAIHAKR"
[9] "VTIMPKDIQLAR"
```

Comment: IIRC the OP wants to _reject_ any sequence _not_ having K or being less than 6 in length.

Comment: If it does then please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer.